# Import huge data from CSV into Neo4j

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

When I try to import huge data into neo4j it gives following error:

there's a field starting with a quote and whereas it ends that quote there seems to be characters in that field after that ending quote. That isn't supported. This is what I read: 'Hello! I am trying to combine 2 variables to one variable. The variables are Public Folder Names and the ParentPath. Both can be found using Get-PublicFolder

Basically I want an array of Public Folders Path and Name so I will have an array like /Engineering/NewUsers

**Below is my code**

```
$parentpath = Get-PublicFolder -ResultSize Unlimited -Identity """ "'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there may be some information lacking from your question, especially about the data that is getting parsed, stack trace a.s.o.

Anyway, I think you can get around this by changing which character is treated as quote character. How are you calling the import tool and which version of Neo4j are you doing this on?

Try including argument `--quote %`, and I'm making this up by just using another character `%` as quote character. Would that help you?